# Javascript document.forms value does not work for Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have searched high and low and I cannot figure out why this code works for Chrome/FF but will not work for IE.

```js
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"].elements["fname"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>

<form name="myForm" action="/action_page_post.php"
onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
<input type="radio" name="fname" id="fname" value="1">1
<input type="radio" name="fname" id="fname" value="2"> 2
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
```

See working demo here: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FEBA861EAACS

Works on Chrome by not IE

Comment: IE does not support that API. (Specifically, the "elements" thing.) You'll have to use something like `.querySelector()` or something.

Comment: ids are singular.

Comment: Elements is JS1.0 so yes it does

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first I would suggest to have different IDs for fìdifferent elements

The value attribute is not supported in IE.

> [elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements): The HTMLFormElement.elements property returns an HTMLFormControlsCollection (HTML 4 HTMLCollection) of all the form controls contained in the FORM element, with the exception of input elements which have a type attribute of image.
>
> You can access a particular element by using either an index or the element name or id.

Because you have two radio:

```
document.forms["myForm"].elements["fname"]
```

returns a collection (nodelist)  not a value. So, you must [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the collection:

```
function validateForm() {
        var x = Array.from(document.forms["myForm"]
           .elements["fname"]).filter(function(ele, idx) {
        return ele.checked;
    });
    if (x.length == 0) {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
```

A different solution can be based on a different selection strategy:

```
[document.querySelector('[name="myForm"] [name="fname"]:checked')][2]
```

The snippet:

```js
function validateForm() {
  var x = document.querySelector('[name="myForm"] [name="fname"]:checked');
  if (x == null) {
      alert("Name must be filled out");
      return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" action="/action_page_post.php"
      onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="fname" id="fname1" value="1">1
    <input type="radio" name="fname" id="fname2" value="2"> 2
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: This works great to make sure a selection has been made on the radio button set.

However is there anyway to get the value in IE? For example I have 2 radio button sets. I want to make sure that the same selection is not made for radio button set 1 and radio button set 2. 

In chrome I can get the values of both radio button sets and compare the results. Any way to do this in IE?